# partial ajax validation yii forms

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I have the following scenario, I created a form on yii and split the form into multiple steps using javascript and css, its all in one single form but visually split into steps, now I have set ajax validation which is working perfectly, the problem is, when I click the "Next" button to go to the next step of the form, I would like to "ajax validate" the fields for that particular step before moving to the next step and so on, any ideas?

BTW, I'm using the standard Yii CActiveForm ajax validation :

```
            $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'formElem',
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'clientOptions' => array('validateOnSubmit' => true),
                    ));
```

Comment: Including code samples will increase the likelihood of a response.

Comment: Need more than that. How about enough to see at least two sections of the form; plus the controller actions you are calling.

Comment: the form is very similar to this one http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/ and I have this on the controller code:     if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) {
         echo CActiveForm::validate( array( $model)); 
         Yii::app()->end(); 
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing some javascript functions to check the .error class based on the response from yii's ajax request, when we click the next button we would check as follow

```
            $(this).closest("fieldset").each(function(){

                $('input').blur();  //This Will trigger yii's CActiveForm ajax requests and return class .error or .success

            });

            var errchk = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.error').length;

            /* Here we check for validation before moving to next step*/
            if(errchk){
                alert("Please Complete all Required fields!");

                return false;
            }else{

                void(0); //continue to slide
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This extension might be helpful for you.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/wizard-behavior/